# How to work with/reference keys in a dictionary with custom type in swift?

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary (myDictionary) where the keys are a custom type (MyClass) that includes 2 properties, name and other. I am trying to set up a picker array and realizing that it might be more complicated because I can't just reference myDictionary.keys because the keys are my custom class. I want the picker array to be populated with the "name" property of MyClass.

I've learned that my class must conform to "Hashable" protocol and that this might have something to do with it but I am somewhat of a noob and do no know much about this "hashable" protocol. here is what I have

```
class MyClass: Codable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var other: MyEnumeration

    init(name: String, other: MyEnumeration) {
        self.name = name
        self.other = other
    }//end init


    //to conform to Hashable - I have NO IDEA what i'm doing here
    static func == (lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.other == rhs.other
    }

    //again i have no idea what i'm doing
    func hash(into hasher: input Hasher) {

    }

}//end MyClass

var myDictionary = [MyClass:String]() 
//as you can see, the keys are the class I created

var pickerArray: [String] = myDictionary.keys.name.sorted() //this is wrong

//the pickerArray is what I want to do - access the "name" property of
//myclass and have it as my picker array options
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want an array of names from all of the keys of your dictionary, you can do:

```
var pickerArray = myDictionary.keys.map { $0.name }.sorted()
```

`myDictionary.keys` gives you all of the `MyClass` instances from the keys. The `.map { $0.name }` converts that array of `MyClass` instances into the corresponding array of names.

And your `hash` method should be:

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(name)
    hasher.combine(other)
}
```

If you look at the documentation for `Hashable`, you can see a clear example of this.